# C# Exception not throwing up to parent form

Tags: c#, forms, exception

I have a  System.Windows.Forms that launches another  form which inherits from a custom form. If I create a button on this 2nd form that creates an exception it does not throw the exception back to the first form where I have a try catch around the showDialog().

FORM 1

```
    try
            {
                using (var d = new Dialog1())
                {
                    d.ShowDialog();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
            }
```

FORM 2

```
 public partial class Dialog1 : TouchBaseForm
    {
        public Dialog1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // var x = K3Data.DigiTickets.API.Api.GetProducsts();
               throw new DivideByZeroException();         
        }
    }
```

The TouchBaseForm inherits from Form.

Whats going on?

How can I catch an exception in first form?

Comment: You already did. What do you get? and why don't you handle the exception?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389504/catch-block-not-catching-exception) probably answers your question.

Comment: This is correct behavior. Exceptions go up the call stack, and while Form 1 may create Form 2, it is not the direct owner of Form 2's context and as such doesn't receive errors like that. That said, to get this type of behavior you could use event listeners and  have the child form catch the error, and send it back to the parent.

Comment: ShowDialog() starts a new message loop, it has a back-stop that prevents exceptions from propagating.  That back-stop raises the Application.ThreadException event.  But only when you don't use a debugger.  Well, you should not be writing code like this.  If you have a reason to "fail" a dialog then assign the this.DialogResult property to DialogResult.Cancel.

Comment: In my test case it does get handled.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. If the 2nds form inherits from Form then it does throw the exception back to form 1.

Answer (score 0):

You are handling it.  And your handler is hiding it:

```
catch (Exception x)
{
}
```

Try this:

```
catch (Exception x)
{
    MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
}
```

If that doesn't work, post the code to `TouchBaseForm` as the problem must lie there.  In my test, the exception was caught and displayed.

Comment: I don't have access to the code for TouchBaseForm. It must be something going on in it as if I inherit from Form all works ok, or at least the exception is passed back to calling method in form 1.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the answer you are looking for in the answer to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352915/how-to-gracefully-close-a-form-if-an-exception-occurs-on-that-form-in-c-sharp?rq=1)

Expanding on HansPassant's comment:  The event methods in forms are called from an event loop.  Windows forms uses event-driven programming rather than the procedural model in which you are thinking.

The ShowDialog method creates a new event loop and waits for the event loop to end, but it does not "call" the event loop so it is not in the call tree of the other form when the exception is thrown.  It gives the illusion that you are calling the dialog, but you really aren't.  Microsoft provided it as a crutch for programmers who were having trouble thinking in the event-driven way-- but if you try to use it for any but the simplest situations, you run into the sort of problems you are having here.

If you want the first form to know about the exception condition in the second form, you have to catch the exception within the second form and pass the information yourself, either with the DialogResult or through the event mechanism.